# How can I use my iPhone as a microphone to my Windows laptop?

Tags: windows

My Windows laptop has a shoddy microphone. I can connect my iPhone to my laptop via USB; I'm not asking about [Bluetooth](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2446). I fancy speaking to my phone's audio input as if it were a mic.

Comment: Title says iPhone, question body says Android - which is it?

Comment: I'm just curious as to why getting an inexpensive USB microphone was overlooked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question body mentions an Android phone twice, whilst the Title says iPhone. Android wins by numerical superiority.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry! Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a "microphone app" to be able to do that. That could for example be the "Wo Mic" or the "Ez-Mic" apps:

https://wolicheng.com/womic/

https://www.ez-mic.com

Comment: The ez-mic link causes Firefox to issue a security warning about the site specifically the certificate.  It may be a simple oversight by the dev but for me, it's red flag and I would avoid it.

Comment: The certificate expired recently - seems like just an oversight. In any case, you can download the app from the App Store for a free 30 minute trial. Personally I would prefer the Wo Mic app I listed first.